# Adjacent excel cells show same cell address on using '=cell("address")' formula. Why is that? Shouldn't they have different addresses?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need the value of cell addresses to implement another solution but I cannot get the correct address. Anyone knows how to fix and get the actual cell address of cells located close to each other.

[image: copying same formula =CELL("address") gives same result for cells with different addresses]

Comment: "*I need the value of cell addresses to implement another solution*"; Are you sure about this? Is this the right means to an end? Maybe ask about your actual problem at hand instead? This reminds me of something called the [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The actual formula is "=MATCH(CELL("address"),$W$15:$W$24,0)". I am checking if the current cell address is the same as detected in an array some place else. The main issue is that the address detected is the same for some reason which is "bug" of excel? Do other people experience the same issue?

Comment: @ShraddhaAvasthy - no, not a bug. Did you read the documentation as noted in the posted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `reference` argument:

```
=CELL("address",L54)
```

From the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf):

> reference:     The cell that you want information about.
>
> Optional
>
> If omitted, the information specified in the info_type argument is returned for cell selected at the time of calculation. If the reference argument is a range of cells, the CELL function returns the information for active cell in the selected range.